# Will I lose all mounts and symbolic links if I resize partitions with gdisk in Linux/Android?

Tags: terminal, mount, partition, symlink, gdisk

I have a rooted Android tablet running Termux terminal. The device has 32gb built-in storage. 6gb is partitioned for "Internal Storage" and is used for apps/games/documents and such. 23gb is partitioned for external storage and is labeled "sdcard".

I would like to use gdisk to expand the "Internal Storage" partition and "Shrink" the sd card partition significantly.

I believe I have the understanding to complete the task. However, I'm unsure whether I'll have to re-create all the mounts and symlinks after the partition resize. I have to delete the two partitions, then recreate them with the same GUID but different sizes.

My question is, after reboot and the new partition table taking effect, will I have to remount all of the file systems? And will I have to re-do all of the symlinks?

I'm fairly new to linux, thanks for any help.

EDIT:

On the partition I plan on shrinking (sdcard), I plan on using `resize2fs` to shrink the filesystem to about 500mb. Then, I plan on using `gdisk` to delete the partition and recreate it with the same GUID to fit exactly with the 500mb.

I plan on doing the same thing in reverse for the partition I want to grow.

My understanding is I can do this without losing any data (as long as the data fits in the resized partition/file system). Which is why I was hoping I wouldn't lose my mounts or symlinks.

The problem is, I have to unmount the partitions I want to modify/delete/recreate with `gdisk`. That being said, will the mounts be recreated on reboot since the GUID is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the internal partition is easy, expanding the filesystem on that partition will not cause data loss. You will have to delete the "sdcard" partition to do so (which you will then re-create), so any data on the current "sdcard" partition will be irrevocably lost, and you will have to take a backup of it and restore it if you want it to be present after the changes.

To expand:

Think of your disk as follows:

```
|------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|  internal  |   sdcard                                      |
|------------|-----------------------------------------------|
 ^^           ^^
```

The up arrows show where the filesystem layout information is kept (I'm vastly oversimplifying, but not to the point of error). When you expand "internal", it creeps out and takes up the area on the disk where the "sdcard" up arrows point to. Once you overwrite those areas by expanding the internal filesystem, the entire sdcard filesystem is lost (absent a significant investment in time and/or money which is usually only undertaken when truly critical, the-company-will-go-out-of-business-if-we-don't-get-it-back, data is lost - think tens of thousands of dollars to start).

You cannot have a partition scheme like this:

```
|------------|-----------------------|-------------------|
|  internal  |  sdcard               | more internal     |
|------------|-----------------------|-------------------|
```

The only way to expand the internal storage is do so this:

```
|-------------------------|------------------------------|
|  expanded internal      |  sdcard                      |
|-------------------------|------------------------------|
```

This isn't specific to Android or Linux, this is simply how disk partitioning works across all operating systems.

Comment: Things are a bit unclear for me... I thought I could resize (shrink) the partition by recreating it with the same GUID, and I won't lose any data. Please see edit on OP

Comment: You can't just shrink the sdcard partition because when you grow the internal partition, it has to be contiguous. Therefore, it will begin consuming what was the start of the sdcard partition. Which is where the filesystem starting information is kept, meaning the filesystem will be corrupted and unrecoverable, requiring reformatting.

Comment: I still don't see why, if I delete the sdcard partition first and recreate it smaller, I can't then expand the internal. However, that still doesn't answer my main question. Will the mounts and symlinks for the internal storage remain after reboot and new GPT taking effect?

Comment: If done correctly, then all data in the internal storage filesystem will remain intact. It is an inherently dangerous operation, but I have done this on multiple occasions on multiple linux systems.

Comment: Ahhh not sure why I didn't grasp that to begin with. Thanks. I have another question but I'll save that for separate post. JUST to be clear. On the Internal Storage partition in this case, will I have to remount it and reestablish symlinks after rebooting?